How to deploy a Streamlit app using Databricks App
I want to run Streamlit using Databricks App.
I have python code (find below) that I can use in visual studio code to run the Streamlit app and even upload  file uploaded to Streamlit to Azure blob storage, but how can I run the Streamlit in databricks as an app and realize the same? i.e. upload the file to Azure blob storage.
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import time
import openpyxl
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os

st.title("site-cluster mapping data")
df_gsl = pd.read_csv(r"C:\users\xxx.xxx\.venv\store_list.csv")
df_bar = df_gsl[['business_unit' , 'site_id']]
df_bar = df_bar.groupby('business_unit').site_id.count().reset_index()
st.bar_chart(data = df_bar, x = 'business_unit' , y = 'site_id')



# Replace with your actual values
connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
container_name = "container-xxxxxxx"
#local_file_path = "sample_input.csv"
blob_name = "sample_input.csv"

def upload_blob(connection_string, container_name, local_file_path , blob_name , df):
    # Create a BlobServiceClient
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

    # Create a container if it doesn't exist
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    
    # Upload the CSV file
    try:
        container_client.upload_blob(name = 'demo_input.csv', data = df.to_csv(), overwrite=True)
        st.write("file has been succesfully uploaded to the blob storage")
    except Exception as e:
        st.error("error uploading the file, please contact code owner")


        

What are the steps? I never created a databricks app before. Thanks in advance!

Are you want to run the above code in Azure Databricks?

@Ian is my solution working for you?

Here is how you create a app in databricks.
Click on New plus button and select App.

Next, for built-in template you select Streamlit and type of app.

you can also select custom template for your own customization.
After, creating you will get endpoint and deployment.

In endpoint you can view the app and deployment is where your files present.
Output in endpoint:

For more information refer this documentation.
